# Crawling with scrapy - bson.errors.InvalidDocument: cannot encode object

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I can’t save data to MongoDB when I tried to scrape Google App store with scrapy. I got an error: `bson.errors.InvalidDocument: cannot encode object`. I searched this error on Google and the result showed there’s something wrong with the data type, but I already converted it into a dictionary data type.

My Pipeline.py file is:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from scrapy import Item


class GpPipeline(object):
    def open_spider(self, spider):
        db_uri = spider.settings.get('MONGODB_URI', 'mongodb://localhost:27017')
        db_name = spider.settings.get('MONGODB_DBNAME', 'scrapy_db')
        db_post = spider.settings.get('MONGODB_DOCNAME', 'apkinfo')

        self.db_client = MongoClient(db_uri)
        self.db = self.db_client[db_name]
        self.post = self.db[db_post]

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.db_client.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        postItem = dict(item)
        self.post.insert(postItem)
        return item

    def insert_db(self, item):
        if isinstance(item, Item):
            item = dict(item)
        self.db.books.insert(item)
```

And error information from terminal is basically like below:

```
2019-11-17 00:50:18 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pinterest> (referer: None)
2019-11-17 00:50:18 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error processing {'app_icon': [<Selector xpath='//img[@itemprop="image"]/@src' data='https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/dVsv8H'>,
              <Selector xpath='//img[@itemprop="image"]/@src' data='https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/HotsP0'>,
              <Selector xpath='//img[@itemprop="image"]/@src' data='https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/jLIPel'>,
              <Selector xpath='//img[@itemprop="image"]/@src' data='https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/4CInZm'>],
 'app_name': [],
 'app_url': 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pinterest'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 649, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/Users/zhanjinyang/Desktop/gp/gp/pipelines.py", line 27, in process_item
    self.post.insert(postItem)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 3195, in insert
    check_keys, manipulate, write_concern)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 614, in _insert
    bypass_doc_val, session)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 602, in _insert_one
    acknowledged, _insert_command, session)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1280, in _retryable_write
    return self._retry_with_session(retryable, func, s, None)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1233, in _retry_with_session
    return func(session, sock_info, retryable)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 597, in _insert_command
    retryable_write=retryable_write)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 589, in command
    self._raise_connection_failure(error)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 750, in _raise_connection_failure
    raise error
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 584, in command
    user_fields=user_fields)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 121, in command
    codec_options, ctx=compression_ctx)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/message.py", line 678, in _op_msg
    flags, command, identifier, docs, check_keys, opts)
bson.errors.InvalidDocument: cannot encode object: <Selector xpath='//img[@itemprop="image"]/@src' data='https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/dVsv8H'>, of type: <class 'scrapy.selector.unified.Selector'>
```

Comment: 1) I highly recommend getting away from using anaconda, it *works* for data scientists (though I try to convince our data scientists not to use it because they don't understand what is built into python vs which is a 3rd party package) but once you start doing **anything** more advanced you should just use pure python. Anaconda can cause some pretty nasty bugs with how it sets up environments 2) Can you print out `item` before the call that makes it crash?

Answer (score 1):

The error message specifies exactly what is wrong:

> `bson.errors.InvalidDocument: cannot encode object: <Selector xpath='//img[@itemprop="image"]/@src' data='https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/dVsv8H'>, of type: <class 'scrapy.selector.unified.Selector'>`

It is because you have grabbed a "live" `Selector` which needs to have its [`.extract()` or `.extract_first()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.8/topics/selectors.html#extract-and-extract-first) called in order to resolve the pointer to its actual page content, which will usually be a `list` or `str` respectively

Thankfully, the `Selector`'s `__str__` representation shows you the xpath it was trying to use, so it should be pretty easy to track down in your code and fix